# how to force yum to remove rpm + rhel 7.5

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

we want to remove openssl-libs and to installed diff openssl version

but yum remove option have huge dependencies list and failed as the following:

```
yum remove openssl-libs
.
.
.
.
.


---> Package spax.x86_64 0:1.5.2-13.el7 will be erased
---> Package speex.x86_64 0:1.2-0.19.rc1.el7 will be erased
---> Package startup-notification.x86_64 0:0.12-8.el7 will be erased
---> Package taglib.x86_64 0:1.8-7.20130218git.el7 will be erased
---> Package tcp_wrappers.x86_64 0:7.6-77.el7 will be erased
---> Package tcp_wrappers-libs.x86_64 0:7.6-77.el7 will be erased
---> Package telepathy-filesystem.noarch 0:0.0.2-6.el7 will be erased
---> Package telepathy-glib.x86_64 0:0.24.0-1.el7 will be erased
---> Package telepathy-logger.x86_64 0:0.8.0-5.el7 will be erased
---> Package tigervnc-license.noarch 0:1.3.1-3.el7 will be erased
---> Package ttmkfdir.x86_64 0:3.0.9-42.el7 will be erased
---> Package tzdata-java.noarch 0:2015g-1.el7 will be erased
---> Package urw-fonts.noarch 0:2.4-16.el7 will be erased
---> Package usbredir.x86_64 0:0.6-7.el7 will be erased
---> Package vte-profile.x86_64 0:0.38.3-2.el7 will be erased
---> Package wavpack.x86_64 0:4.60.1-9.el7 will be erased
---> Package webrtc-audio-processing.x86_64 0:0.1-5.el7 will be erased
---> Package xcb-util.x86_64 0:0.4.0-2.el7 will be erased
---> Package xkeyboard-config.noarch 0:2.14-1.el7 will be erased
---> Package xml-common.noarch 0:0.6.3-39.el7 will be erased
---> Package xmlrpc-c.x86_64 0:1.32.5-1905.svn2451.el7 will be erased
---> Package xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.5-20.el7 will be erased
---> Package xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.5-9.el7 will be erased
---> Package xorg-x11-server-common.x86_64 0:1.17.2-10.el7 will be erased
---> Package xorg-x11-server-utils.x86_64 0:7.7-14.el7 will be erased
---> Package xorg-x11-xkb-utils.x86_64 0:7.7-12.el7 will be erased
---> Package yajl.x86_64 0:2.0.4-4.el7 will be erased
---> Package yelp-xsl.noarch 0:3.14.0-1.el7 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

in the last lines we see remove systemd and yum

```
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

how we can force yum remove in order to remove openssl-libs rpm?

Answer (score 0):

I formally advice you to not delete openssl version provided with the os core, this will break as you seen your package manager "yum" and "systemd" that depends mostly on it.
Instead i would recommend to :

- Upgrade the system to **RHEL6** using  **yum**

Or

- Install new **openssl** OS independent package, then your system packages and application will be based and this featured one :

  `mkdir ~/src/`

  `cd ~/src/`

  `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2a.tar.gz`

  `tar -zxvf openssl-*.tar.gz`

  `cd openssl-*`

  `./config -fpic shared && make && make install`

  `echo "/usr/local/ssl/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf`

  `ldconfig`

Now check your openssl version :

```
openssl version
```